# How can i get rid of askpass authentication pop-up?

Tags: windows, git, atlassian-sourcetree

This box pops up constantly and points to an old git host that we no longer use.  I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling SourceTree and checked all the authentication settings but there is no reference to this anywhere that i can find.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try doing this and it should point to new URL.

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/myName/myRepo.git
```

Also, please check .git/config file for the URL listed in the [remote "origin"] Section.

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the protocol to git instead of https.

`https` will always prompt you for password unless you set up the credentials configuration to remember password.

The easiest way is to switch to git protocol but if you cant ill explain how to set up git to remember password.

#### How to tell git to remember password

Basically you will have to use the following configuration based upon your OS

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from what I believe the OP was asking for, which would be to stop having this prompt and just be authenticated automatically to the repo they want, I want to mention one other silly thing. If you just opened source tree on accident like me instead of a different git client, then clicking cancel on this box, or closing it from the task bar, or even ending the process from taskmanager will all result in the box continually coming back to annoy you. Only clicking the X button in the upper right seems to make it actually go away.